# Can any of the SAS METADATA_GET* functions give information on authorizations

Tags: sas, metadata, authorize

We use SAS in a client server setup with a metadata server.
I use SAS [Functions for Reading Metadata](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lrmeta/p0o5rdel8tgzgsn1iqhdwybgui7k.htm)
to read attributes and relations of SAS libraries, tables, folders etc from the metadata.

To verify our setup, we would like to list who can access what, i.e. to programmatically retrieve what you can find in SAS Management Console on the Authorization tab of an object's properties:
[image]

Does anyone know where to find that information?

For your inspiration: I usually use the functions to read metadata in a datastep, but this time, I used `Lua`

```
proc Lua restart;
submit;
    debug = true
    maxDo = 9

    function getObjAttr(uri, attrList, old_obj)
        new_obj = old_obj or {}
        if debug then new_obj.uri = uri:gsub("%s+$", "") end

        -- list only the requested attributes
        local val_256 = string.rep("v",256)
        for _, attrName in ipairs(attrList) do
            if sas.METADATA_GETATTR(uri, attrName, val_256) >= 0 then
                new_obj[attrName] = 
                (   attrName:sub(1, 2) == 'Is'
                    or  attrName == 'NumRows'
                    or  attrName == 'UsageVersion' ) and tonumber(val_256)
                or  val_256:gsub("%s+$", ""):gsub("^%s+", "")
            end
        end
        
        -- list all properties
        local prop_256 = string.rep("p",256)
        for prop_nr = 1, maxDo do
            if sas.METADATA_GETNPRP(uri, prop_nr, prop_256, val_256) < 0 then break end
            new_obj["_".. prop_256:gsub("%s+$", "")] = val_256:gsub("%s+$", "")
        end
        return new_obj
    end

    -- find the path to an object
    function getLocation(uri)
        local folder_256 = string.rep("f",256)
        if sas.METADATA_GETNASN(uri, 
            string.find(uri, ":Tree") and 'ParentTree' or 'Trees', 
            1, folder_256) >= 0 
        then 
            return getObjAttr(folder_256, {'name'}, {location = getLocation(folder_256)}) 
        end
    end

    -- collect all libraries
    lib_set = {}
    for obj_nr = 1, maxDo do
        local uri_256 = string.rep("u",256)
        -- test with a limited set
        if sas.METADATA_GETNOBJ("SASLibrary?@name contains '_CBC'", obj_nr, uri_256) < 0 then break end
        -- to get all, change to SASLibrary?@id contains '.'

        lib_set[uri_256:gsub("%s+$", ""):gsub(".+%.", "")] = 
            getObjAttr(uri_256, {'name', 'libref', 'engine'}, {location = getLocation(uri_256)})
    end
    if debug then print("Lua: ".. table.tostring(lib_set)) end

    -- to be completed with code to export the relevant info to sas datasets
endsubmit;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible in pure macro.  However - it can be done with batch tools.

I started a PR to the [core](https://github.com/sasjs/core) library that would make use of these - if you feel like finishing it off, be my guest!  Our current SAS 9 environment does not have X Command so I can't test it.

https://github.com/sasjs/core/pull/45/files

Comment: Thanks Allan, but we disabled  X command too. However, I can run `sas-set-metadata-access`  on the linux server and process the result in SAS. Both can be scheduled overnight too. _(By the way, I don't execute my functions from macro but either from a `data` step or Lua)_

Comment: didn't know you could run metadata functions from lua!

I'll give you one tip - avoid the `io` library, it isn't supported in Viya 4

Comment: I added my `Lua` code to the question, so you can have a look.

Comment: Could I use `sas-show-metadata-access` on worspace servers too? `sas-list-objects -profile SASAdmin -types Server|grep Workspace` list them as `SASApp_XYZ - Workspace Server(Server)`, but `sas-show-metadata-access -profile SASAdmin 'SASApp_XYZ - Workspace Server(Server)'` gives not result.